# Access 2013 Training Tracker Join Questions

Tags: sql, ms-access

This seems like it should be easy, but for some reason I can't work it out.

I have a table, *e*, with my employees in.
I have a table, *t*, with my trainings in.
I have a table, *e_t*, which records the date on which an employee completed a training.

What I want to do is create a query which shows me an employee's 'training status'.

I've got this far:

```
SELECT t.*, e_t.*
FROM t

LEFT JOIN e_t ON (
  t.ID = e_t.Training
  AND e_t.e = [EmpID]
);
```

(In this instance, [EmpID] is a parameter I'm passing in).

It *sort of* works, in that it returns something that I could use to make a report, but due to Access's quirks, if you use 'AND' in a JOIN statement, it then makes the recordset not updatable, meaning I can't hook it up easily to a form.

The eventual goal would be to be able to add in the date that a training was completed from the view itself:

```
Training | Date Completed
======== | ==============
Train 1  | 01/01/2015
Train 2  | 01/02/2015
Train 3  | 
Train 4  |
Train 5  | 01/03/2015
```

Anyone have an ideas about the best way to do this? So far I'm wondering if the easiest way might be to create this 'view' as a report, and embed a button on the report with a macro that pops up a new form, and automatically populates the e_t.Employee and the e_t.Training value automatically, leaving only the e_t.CompletionDate field for the user to select, but that seems a bit like overkill.

Any help appreciated!

Sample table date:

*e*

```
ID | Name | Employee No
== | ==== | ===========
 1 | Bill | 12345678
```

*t*

```
ID | TrainingName | Duration
== | ============= | ========
 1 | Training 1    | 60
```

*e_t*

```
ID | Employee | Training | DateCompleted
== | ======== | ======== | =============
 1 |        1 |        1 | 01/01/2015
```

Comment: Both sample table data and the expected result make the problem much easier to understand.

Comment: Sorry, gone back and added some sample table data to the original question - it should look like a table with trainings down the left, and either a date or a blank on the right.